# Set an attribute binding with Renderer2 and setProperty() on created element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-renderer2

I create a new element in the DOM with

`const newTag = this.renderer2.createElement('g', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');`

Then I would like to add a bind attribute with

`this.renderer2.setProperty(newTag, 'transform', initialPosition);`

But I get in the browser console

`ERROR TypeError: setting getter-only property "transform"`

How can I make this work, or at least create an attribute binding between a new element created in the DOM to a component variable.

Comment: Try this.renderer2.setStyle(newTag, 'transform', initialPosition);

Comment: Try `setAttribute` instead of `setProperty` for `transform`.

Comment: I tried already setAttribute but not setStyle, but if I change the initialPosition variable inside my component later : does angular change detector will update the transform attribute in the g tag created ?